# How to set up Inkscape's preferences to export only to PDF or SVG

Tags: inkscape, export, file-format, mac

Is there a setting (or hidden preference) to tell Inkscape's to ***show** only a couple specific file formats* in the "Save as"/"Export" menu (out of the 20+ choices available) and ignore the rest?
I'm interested in a method for MacOS (11 Big Sur), but other solutions might be useful to others for reference.

I use Inkscape (1.1.1) pretty frequently at work.
We save and archive the .svg files and export to .pdf (for embedding in LaTeX) – all within Inkscape's GUI, via the "File > Save as" function.
We consistently need these two formats, *and only ever these two*.

With every edit or later revision of an image, there is a good amount of back and forth between formats. Picking/clicking the desired format from the 25 items in the drop-down list is a somewhat tedious and error-prone proposition (what with the notoriously laggy GUI on Mac and the drop-down menus disappearing when not being clicked).

I am aware of one possible workaround ([save SVG and export PDF via command line](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50222)), but we are looking for a solution *within the GUI* that allows to *narrow down the **visible** formats to only these two*:

[image]

I couldn't find anything in the "Inkscape > Preferences" menu, nor in the system files where the preferences are stored (`/Users/~/Library/Application Support/org.inkscape.Inkscape`).
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Hi. There's no such functionality as far as I'm aware.  You'd need to reprogram the application, which is way beyond the scope of GDSE.

Comment: @BillyKerr: I see. I'll post a feature request then, in case the dev team deems this a useful feature. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer. But you don't need to scroll through all the items on that drop-down list. You can simply change the extension of the file in the **Name** box and click **Save** button (or hit Enter). Inkscape will automatically guess the format from the extension and save the document accordingly.

**Update**:

Inkscape 1.2 (now in beta release) redesigned the export dialog. By default<sup>*</sup>, you can export only to the following formats:

[[image: Export formats1]

---

<sub>*: You can show all the formats from the settings.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! My requested solution is actually impossible, as was pointed out, so I find your workaround very helpful!

Comment: Interesting to learn that 1.2 won't show the complete list by default. In which tab of the settings will the option to switch this back on, be?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: You can access the settings from this tab: https://i.imgur.com/jXjqTNc.png Note that this is relevant only for the "Export" dialog independent from the ordinary "Save" and "Save as" list.

Comment: @s.ouchene Thanks a lot!